# using Oracle JDBC driver implicit caching feature

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, driver

I am pretty sure that somebody else already asked this question, but I still couldn't find a satisfactory answer to it.
  So, here is my scenario: I want to use the Oracle's JDBC driver implicit statement caching (documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/stmtcach.htm#i1072607)

I need to use the connections from a 3rd party JDBC pool provider (to be more specific, Tomcat JDBC) and I have no choice there.

The problem is that the way to enable the implicit caching is a two-step process (accordingly to the documentation):

1.

> Call setImplicitCachingEnabled(true) on the connection
>    or
>   Call OracleDataSource.getConnection with the ImplicitCachingEnabled
>   property set to true. You set ImplicitCachingEnabled by calling
>   OracleDataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true)

2.

> In addition to calling one of these methods, you also need to call
>   OracleConnection.setStatementCacheSize on the physical connection. The
>   argument you supply is the maximum number of statements in the cache.
>   An argument of 0 specifies no caching.

I can live with 1 (somehow I can configure my pool to use the `OracleDataSource` as a primary connection factory and on that I can set the `OracleDataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true)`).
But at the second step, I already need the connection to be present in order to call the `setStatementCacheSize`.

My question is if there is any possibility to specify at the data source level a default value for the `statementCacheSize` so that I can get from the `OracleDataSource` connections that are already enabled for implicit caching.

PS: some related questions I found here:
[Oracle jdbc driver: implicit statement cache or setPoolable(true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499179/oracle-jdbc-driver-implicit-statement-cache-or-setpoolabletrue)

**Update (possible solution):**

Eventually I did this:

1. Created a native connection pool using `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`.
2. Created a tomcat JDBC connection pool using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` that uses the native one (see the property `dataSource`).
3. Enabled via AOP a poincut so that after the execution of 'execution(public java.sql.Connection oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection())' I pickup the object and perform the setting I wanted.

The solution works great; I am just unhappy that I had to write some boilerplate to do it (I was expecting a straight-forward property).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The white paper [Oracle JDBC Memory Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/memory.pdf) says that

> The 11.2 drivers also add a new property to enable the Implicit Statement Cache.
>
> `oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize`
>
> The value of the property is an
> integer string, e.g. “100”. It is the initial size of the statement
> cache. Setting the property to a positive value enables the Implicit
> Statement Cache. **The default is “0”. The property can be set as a
> System property via -D** or as a connection property via getConnection.

Comment: Didn't get the chance to validate the solution but the description is straight-forward. This is what I was looking for. I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only change statement cache size through `OracleConnection.setStatementCacheSize` method.

Instead of modifying your application to call `OracleConnection.setStatementCacheSize` on every connection, you can create a **JDBC interceptor**.

```
@Override
public void reset(ConnectionPool pool, PooledConnection connection) {

    if (connection == null) {
        return;
    }

    Connection original = connection.getConnection();

    if (!(original instanceof OracleConnection)) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (!((OracleConnection) original).getImplicitCachingEnabled() && implicitCachingEnabled) {

            ((OracleConnection) original).setImplicitCachingEnabled(implicitCachingEnabled);

            log.info("Activated statement cache");

            ((OracleConnection) original).setStatementCacheSize(statementCacheSize);

            log.info("Statement cache size set to " + statementCacheSize);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have studied this option - the problem that I have with the interceptors is that they get called every time a connection is returned from the pool. What I wanted is something just for the initialization. However, I came up with a solution eventually. Please see above.