# HikariCP prepared statement cache

Tags: oracle, caching, hikaricp, connection-pool

I was looking into HikariCP for using it in one of my projects. The [statement cache section](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#statement-cache) of the project page in github says that it doesn't support prepared statement cache at the connection pool level.

But the [initialization section](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization) has the below code snippet

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons");
config.setUsername("bart");
config.setPassword("51mp50n");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

and it sets prepared statement cache config. Is it being configured for the connection pool or the driver below? 
Also what are the properties supported by addDataSourceProperty method?

Comment: Caching is provided by the driver.

Answer (score 1):

The datasource is configured and used by MySql in your case.

Basically you can send relevant properties to your implementation.

For example for oracle you can send

```
dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar", "true");
```

And this property will be used in oracle implementation

HikariCP save it in properties and copy it to driver Properties and use it on connect :

```
for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
         driverProperties.setProperty(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
      }
....
driver.connect(jdbcUrl, driverProperties);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand that the caching is for the driver and we can set the driver properties using addDataSourceProperty.  But I couldn't find the data source property to be set for enabling cache in oracle driver (as you said the sample code snippet is for MySQL).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167108/using-oracle-jdbc-driver-implicit-caching-feature