# When connections will be closed when using hibernate and oracle implicit connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection

I am using hibernate and oracle implicit connection pool for my application

**DataSource configuration**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe" />
        <property name="user" value="abc" />
        <property name="password" value="abc" />
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"></property>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="MinLimit">10</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
                <prop key="InitialLimit">10</prop>
                <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">200</prop>
                <prop key="PropertyCheckInterval">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**EntityManager Configuration**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryDefault"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MaterializedView" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/jpa-context.xml");
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = (EntityManagerFactory) applicationContext.getBean("entityManagerFactoryDefault");
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++");
    entityManagerFactory.close();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

I don't understand why connections are not closed even after closing entityManagerFactory.
When i query

```
select username,last_call_et "last call", status,PREV_HASH_VALUE  from v$session WHERE status = 'INACTIVE';
```

I see connections are INACTIVE status with count same as initial limit specified in connectionCacheProperties .
Is something wrong with my code or this is the actual behavior ?

Comment: Why would the `DataSource` be closed? What if it's still in use? The `EntityManagerFactory` isn't necessarily the only thing using the pool.

Comment: What else would be using DataSource?

Comment: It is working fine if i enable implicitCachingEnabled.Connections are closed after entityMangerFactory.close

Comment: What else? Anything else. `EntityManagerFactory` doesn't own a datasource, it only uses it.

Comment: All connections are closed with implicitCachingEnabled.

Comment: `implicitCachingEnabled` affects the [statement cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167108/using-oracle-jdbc-driver-implicit-caching-feature). It's an entirely different thing.