# Oracle JDBC Optimization : Enable PreparedStatement caching in a Spring boot Application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a Spring Boot REST application that's connected to an Oracle database. We're using JDBC using JdbcTemplate. The Oracle database properties are obtained through these 3 **application.properties** settings:

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.username
spring.datasource.password
```

This application is using the HikariCP. From the HikariCP website, I came to know that this pool doesn't cache PreparedStatements because the JDBC driver is best setup to do that.

Now, where and what would I specify to ensure these :

1. That the Oracle JDBC Driver(ojdbc7.jar) caches PreparedStatements. Is there a way to customize the number of PreparedStatements that it can cache.
2. From https://howtodoinjava.com/java/jdbc/best-practices-to-improve-jdbc-performance/, we see that

   > Ensure that your database is set to the maximum packet size and that
   >   the driver matches that packet size. For fetching larger result sets,
   >   this reduces the number of total packets sent/received between the
   >   driver and server.

In pursuance of the above, what are the steps required to

1. find the Oracle DB Server packet size
2. find if the Oracle DB Server is set to the maximum packet size
3. find set the Oracle JDBC driver's(ojdbc8.jar) packet size.

Any other (Oracle) JDBC performance optimization tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it more suitable to ask in dba site? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle

Comment: @user7294900 Not really, because this is about configuring the JDBC driver (assuming it even has such a configuration option), which makes this a programming question and not a DBA question.

Answer (score 3):

Hi the function Enable Prepared statement caching has nothing to do neither with Spring, neither with REST. This function is a question of negotiation only between your datasource, your JDBC driver and your database. In order to find out how to set it up read the relevant documentation about your driver , datasource and database.

When it comes to Hikari, the coirrect way to do this is(notice **datasource2**, rename to **datasource** to enable autoconfiguration):

```
spring:
  datasource2:
      dataSourceClassName: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDatasource
       .....
       ......
      configuration:
            maximumPoolSize: 25  
            data-source-properties:
               ImplicitCachingEnabled: true
               MaxStatements: 100
```

The properties inside your configuration will be passed straight to the underlying driver.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties2() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean()
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource2.configuration")
public DataSource hikariDatasource() {


    return dataSourceProperties2().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
```

}

This example uses manual initialization of the underlying datasource.

Comment: This is MySQL config, `cachePrepStmts` is a MySQL JDBC driver option see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/28a2afd3e6251d9cb3e8fdf1dc2e65c8f06c2b9f/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L437 and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: @KarolDowbecki actualy thgis example was running on DB2 :)

Comment: Point is `data-source-properties` is a proxy, it passes properties to the driver so if the driver doesn't have `cachePrepStmts` property it won't work. ojdbc8 driver doesn't have this properties.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki maybe you should change the question then to "What property do you need in order to enable statement caching in Oracle" instead of involving spring boot REST and whatever. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/stmtcach.htm#i1070438

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov : Hi, I'm the OP here. I removed the REST part. I needed the configuration properties for Oracle 11/12 using ojdbc7.jar

Comment: @anjanb are the properties from my post not working ? The data-source-properties: element is dire4ctly passed the underlying datasource which in your case is the oracle one.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking the documentation to ensure that your `ojdbc8.jar` matches the database server version. There are different versions of `ojdbc8.jar` for 11g, 11gR2, 12c.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068100/1602555), you need `oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize` property to be set in the JDBC driver. [This article](https://erikwramner.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/oracle-jdbc-memory-settings/) mentions few more JDBC driver properties e.g. `oracle.jdbc.freeMemoryOnEnterImplicitCache` or `oracle.jdbc.maxCachedBufferSize`. You need to check docs for your driver version to confirm that these properties are available.

This can be passed using Spring Boot HikariCP [`spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) option. Double check docs for your Spring Boot version, this property was renamed at least once:

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize: 100
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize: 100
```

You might also be interested in [statement fetch size](https://makejavafaster.blogspot.com/2015/06/jdbc-fetch-size-performance.html) but this optimization is usually applied to each statement separately.

Comment: Hi @Karol, thanks. How would I rephrase these properties using application.properties file instead of a application.yml file ?

Answer (score 0):

- Enable Statement caching through

`oracleDataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true)`

- Choose the right cache size to best utilize the memory

`connection.setStatementCacheSize(10)` 
Try to be closer to the number of most used statements 
Default statement cache size is 10

- Fallback if you cannot change the application to use statement
  caching

`session_cached_cursors = 50
Connection.setStatementCacheSize(10)`

Comment: I don't have access to the OracleDatasource. All I have access to is the JdbcTemplate from which I will get the Hikari datasource . I also don't go to the connection level -- I work at the JdbcTemplate level.